# How can I see the result of using an obfuscator for .net?

Tags: c#, obfuscation, eazfuscator

I've downloaded Eazfuscator, installed it, and drag and drop my project into the indicated green field in Eazfuscator. Then I rebuild my solution in release mode and in Release folder.  Using Total Commander, I press F4 on the dll and I can still see all the sql queries which I wrote in c#. I thought that eazfuscator hid all queries and all method names (method names are visible also)?

Comment: Are you sure you are using it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code obfuscation and encryption are two different things.

An obfuscator doesn't necessarily encrypt the strings in your code. It (basically) renames classes, methods, parameters and variables so that the intent of your code is obfuscated. The assigned values like strings stay the same.

As far as I can tell Eazfuscator features string encryption, but I don't know if it has to be configured in some way.

Comment: Ok, I did everything again and now its ok.